# My web api route map is returning multiple actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The requested URL: `http://localhost/api/access/blob`

The route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AccessApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

The defined actions:

```
public class AccessController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/access/blob
    [HttpGet]
    public string Blob()
    {
        return "blob shared access signature";
    }

    // GET api/access/queue
    [HttpGet]
    public string Queue()
    {
        return "queue shared access signature";
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
    System.String Blob() on type Project.Controllers.AccessController 
    System.String Queue() on type Project.Controllers.AccessController
```

Why isn't it finding the appropriate action?

Comment: is your new route listed above default?

Comment: No. If I remove the default, it seems to find it. Alternatively, if I switch one from `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`, that works too.

Comment: OIC, your new route is first. then I'm stuck

Comment: Default route was first. Removed it and all is well (wasn't using it anyway, residual code from previous mucking around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `DefaultApi` route configuration on the WebApiConfig.cs file. Add just your configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AccessApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
    }
}
```

And it will work with the url:

`http://localhost/api/access/blob`

`http://localhost/api/access/queue`